# How to sort the Attribute Set list on the create new product

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, products, attribute-set, sort

Can anyone tell me how to **sort the order of attribute sets when creating new products** in Magento.

From question: [How to sort the Attribute Set list on the Manage Products Grid dropdown menu?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52289/how-to-sort-the-attribute-set-list-on-the-manage-products-grid-dropdown-menu)
I can see how it is done for the manage product grid. But it is even more needed when creating new products

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so once you've created the module described in the answer you posted you need to add the following:

Change the `config.xml` to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyProject_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyProject_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>MyProject_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_settings>MyProject_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Settings</catalog_product_edit_tab_settings>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then create the following file `app/code/local/MyProject/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Settings.php`

```
<?php
class MyProject_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Settings 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Settings
{
    public function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('settings', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Create Product Settings')));

        $entityType = Mage::registry('product')->getResource()->getEntityType();

        $fieldset->addField('attribute_set_id', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute Set'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute Set'),
            'name'  => 'set',
            'value' => $entityType->getDefaultAttributeSetId(),
            'values'=> Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType->getId())
                ->setOrder('attribute_set_name', 'asc')
                ->load()
                ->toOptionArray()
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('product_type', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Type'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Type'),
            'name'  => 'type',
            'value' => '',
            'values'=> Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray()
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('continue_button', 'note', array(
            'text' => $this->getChildHtml('continue_button'),
        ));

        $this->setForm($form);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I did not manage to make it work my creating a module as suggested in the linked thread. I can only make it work by changing the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php as descibed.
Using magento 1.9.2.3