# Attribute set sort order has gone - how to rebuild?

Tags: magento-1, collection, attribute-set

This code returned attributes set for dropdown menu - **ordered by attribute set name** ...

```
$sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
    ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
    ->load()
    ->toOptionHash();
```

Suddenly it changed to display sets orded by ID instead of name ...

What is your default sort for this code? Why could it change? Would like to understand, why behavoir changed ...

---

Update:

<s>Checked `eav_attribute_set` table wher sort order is stored ... and its set to 0 for all set - only "default" has value 10.</s>

Last thing I've made was to create a new set ....

No change ...

---

Update:

Found this ... [How to sort the Attribute Set list on the Manage Products Grid dropdown menu?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52289/how-to-sort-the-attribute-set-list-on-the-manage-products-grid-dropdown-menu), BUT why did it work before?

(Whats your sort order for attribute sets?)

---

Update:

Suddenly sort order (by set name) is correct again. Without any changes made. Just added further sets.

Ideas? (Refreshed cache/indexes already yesterday)